# How siblings are sharing their scope under following directive structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have following directive structure.

```
 <test-widget-body>
         <test-task-list-filter>
         </test-task-list-filter>
         <test-task-list>
                <test-datatable config="dtConfig" columns="dtColumns" api="dtApi"></test-datatable>
         </test-task-list>
 </test-widget-body>
```

Here are respective directives:

**test-datatable**

```
angular.module('testDatatable').directive('testDatatable', function () {
  var directive = {
    controller: 'testDatatableController',
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      config: '=',
      columns: '=',
      api: '=',
    },
    link: lnkFunction,
    template: '<table class="table"></table>',
  };

  return directive;

}
```

**testTaskList**

```
angular.module('testTask').directive('testTaskList', function () {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'testListController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    templateUrl: '/app/test/directives/test-list/test-list.html',
    link: {
      pre: preLink
    }
  };
  function preLink(){
    var dtColumns = [{
    ----
    }];
    var dtConfig =[];
    var dtApi =[];

  }

}
```

**testTaskListFilter**

```
angular.module('testTask').directive('testTaskListFilter', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'testListFilterController',
    templateUrl: '/app/test/directives/test-list/test-list-filter.html'
  };
});
```

**testWidgetBody**

```
angular.module('testWidgetGrid').directive('testWidgetBody', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    link: function ($scope, element) {

}

}
```

Here I'm able to access `dtConfig` `dtColumns` `dtApi` objects inside `testListFilterController` controller.
How is this possible as `<test-task-list-filter>` and  `<test-task-list>` are siblings.
Can anyone explain what is happening in this scenario.

**Note:** I'm able to access that object when I perform some click action not while directive rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the declarations for `testTaskListFilter` directive and the `testTaskList` directive, neither of them have isolate scopes. You can declare isolate scopes by doing one of the following in the directive: `scope: true` or `scope: {}` (like in your `testDatatable`) directive.

Thus, any directive that does not declare its own scope inherits its *parent's*. So, `testTaskListFilter` and `testTaskList` are both using the same scope. This means that you're then able to

> access `dtConfig` `dtColumns` `dtApi` objects inside `testListFilterController` controller

Here's the [Angular wiki post](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for understanding scopes and scope inheritance